# Synchronizing an Oracle database using "last modified" timestamps in the face of transactions

Tags: java, database, oracle, synchronization, timestamp

We've got an enterprise Oracle 12c database that we'd like to synchronize with an analytical database using a Java program (which will be doing a lot of aggregating during the sync), using a per-row "last modified" timestamp in the Oracle database to determine which rows need to be synced.  The general algorithm is

```
void run() {
  Timestamp lastRead = loadLastRead(); // load last logged timestamp
  while(true) {
    rows = select * from Oracle database where last_modified >= lastRead;
    lastRead = rows.max(last_modified); // max timestamp from the retrieved rows
    saveLastRead(lastRead); // log the timestamp in case the program crashes
    sleep(five minutes or whatever);
  }
}
```

My concern is that I might run into the following situation:

1. Transaction starts on row R1, calculates timestamp of T1
2. last_modified timestamp T2 written to row R2
3. Sync using lastRead of T0
4. Sync ends, lastRead updated to T2
5. Transaction commits with timestamp T1 < T2 on row R1

And now I'll never sync row R1 (until new data is written to it, assuming I'm not foiled by a transaction again).  I can try to minimize the timestamp skew, but I don't see a way to eliminate it.

One solution would be to do something like

```
lastRead = rows.max(last_modified) - C;
```

where C is five seconds or some other time span that we don't think that many transactions will exceed - the problem is that with too large a C we'll be re-syncing too much data, and with too small a C we might get some outlier transactions exceeding C

Another solution would be to use a per-row version number, which would require a lot of bookkeeping and would almost certainly hurt the performance of `select * from Oracle database`

Comment: What database product do you use for storing your analytical database?

Comment: @BobJarvis Cassandra, which in turn talks to Tableau for the majority of the reporting

Comment: You might be better off considering Change Data Capture (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm)

Comment: Or, if you have a lot of money, GoldenGate (http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/acquisitions/goldengate/index.html)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp That's exactly what I was looking for; please submit an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, trying to use a query based on a timestamp column is not a reliable method for picking up changes, unless you introduce a significant delay or system downtime (e.g. running an overnight batch process when concurrent changes are unlikely to be made).

Another method that some have used is to use a monotonically increasing numeric ID column based on an ORDERed Oracle sequence. One problem with this approach may be how ordered sequences perform in a RAC system.

A [Materialized View](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17516/tdpii_reppit.htm#TDPII048) (as suggested by Lalit) would be one option.

Some other options depending on your budget and the complexity of your requirements include:

- [Change Data Capture](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm)
- [Oracle GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/acquisitions/goldengate/index.html)
- [Oracle Data Integrator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/overview/index.html) (ODI)

Note: GoldenGate and ODI are complementary products and can work well together.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `MATERIALIZED VIEW` to keep the data in sync. You don't have to manually write a program for that, `Oracle` would do it for you.

You can read more about materialized views in documentation https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302